# How to setup authentication between telegraf & graphite?

Tags: graphite, telegraf

I've got a graphite server set up with authentication turned on, and some metrics in telegraf (on a different server) that I'd like to send to it using the [telegraf graphite plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/graphite).

Obviously it fails without setting up any authentication from telegraf for that connection (thankfully :-) ), with a `Could not write to any Graphite server in cluster`.

But my question is how *should* I set up telegraf to authenticate? I notice that for other plugins (e.x. the [influxdb](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/influxdb) one) there are config params for username/password, but are not any for the graphite plugin.

It seems like this is a pretty common integration, so it seems odd that it wouldn't be supported. So **how do I authenticate between the two?** Ideally I won't have to do any shenanigans with proxies.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you, but I am debugging a telegraf-graphite connection and curious where are you finding that error?